# Linear Algebra change equation to avoid matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a better (faster) way to run the following program:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    x=A^-1*B;
    A = change(A);
    save(x);
}
```

where $A$ and $B$ are matrices, element of $\mathbb{R}^{100\times 100}$.

Because this is within a loop, and $A$ is changing every time, I want to avoid generating the inverse of $A$. 
So I am looking for some equation which returns x, where x is the same than in this equation.
$B$ is not changing, so it is fine if I have $B^{-1}$ within the equation. If B needs to be inverted, I would do this ones, and the algorithm would be fast again...

Comment: yes, B is also 100x100

Comment: In what way does $A$ change?

Comment: The values are changing... complete columns. the size will be not changing

Comment: There's no pattern at all to be found in the way $A$ changes? Does every column change?

Comment: nearly every column... there is no real pattern... to be honest, I have 1000 different A's they have nothing to do with each other except the size

Comment: But all the A's need to be inverted, and multiplied with B... so I thought, that if I change the equation, so that B needs to be inverted, the hole algorithm would be faster, because calculating the inverse of an matrix takes O(n³) where n is the size

Comment: nice idear with glueing... but in fact, that makes no difference :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A dumb way :)

Instead of computing $A^{-1}B$ compute the inverse $X^{-1} = (A^{-1}B)^{-1} = B^{-1}A$ 
where $B^{-1}$ is computed once. The loop is faster, however you would have stored the inverse of $X$ at each iteration. In that way, if the loop consists of $M$ iterations and the size of of $A$ is $N \times N$, you would have saved $O(MN^3)$. As @Yves Daoust points out, evidently, you have not computed $X$

## Exploiting the structure of $A$

Example $1$: If $A$ is "rank-$1$" updating ($A_{n+1} = A_n + u_n v_n^\textsf{T})$, then you could use the Sherman–Morrison formula :
$$\left(A + uv^\textsf{T}\right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {A^{-1}uv^\textsf{T}A^{-1} \over 1 + v^\textsf{T}A^{-1}u}$$
You'd only compute an inverse ONCE. Why? Assume $A_0$ is your "initial matrix". Compute its inverse, and call it $A_0^{-1}$ you can compute $A_1^{-1} = (A_0 + uv^T)^{-1}$ by the above formula by replacing $A^{-1}$ by $A_0^{-1}$ and so on ..

Example $2$: If the update is more complex, like $A_{n+1} = A_n + U_nC_nV_n$, you can use Woodbury's identity, which tells you
$$\left(A + UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}$$
Your speed gain here depends on the size of $C$. Extreme cases are when:(i) $C_n$ is scalar (you return to the case in example $1$), (ii) $C_n$ is arbitrary and is of size $n$, then you basically gain no speed.

Comment: Yep, but you still don't have $X$.

Comment: yes @YvesDaoust you are right

Comment: so, x^-1 = B^-1 * A... so the claculation of x^-1 is faster. but afterwards I need to invert x again... so it would be as fast as now

Comment: @Thomas, all I'm saying is if your matrices are random with no structure, there's nothing fancy that could be done. However, exploiting structure of $A$ (like in the two examples), you would gain pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you *could* solve this problem as stated, and could compute $x$ without computing $A^{-1}$.

Consider what you'd produce if $B$ happened to be the identity: on each iteration, you would produce $A^{-1}B = A^{-1}$.

That means that somehow, without computing $A^{-1}$, you'd manage to compute $A^{-1}$. If you could do that, it would be quite remarkable.

In short: there's no hope for solving the general problem you've posed.

If there's some special structure to $B$ (e.g., if $B$ is the zero matrix!), then maybe you can get somewhere. But as written: hopeless.

Comment: okay, I thought so... I also tryied to turn it around many ways... but can't find a solution without inverting A... Seems like you are right, and I have to deal with my original solution, which is slow :(. But anyway, thanks a lot for your time!